# How a group could be attached to a screen in Java

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

The main class has following part for `FXMLLoader`

```
public void GeomStart() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader (MYGUI.class.getResource (
                "Geom.fxml"));
        AnchorPane geomPage = (AnchorPane) loader.load ();
        rootLayout.setCenter (geomPage);
        primaryStage.setScene (rootScene);
        GeomController controller = loader.getController ();
        controller.setMainApp (this);            
        controller.setMyStage (primaryStage);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println (" Problem in loading geometry set");
        Logger.getLogger (MYGUI.class.getName ()).log (Level.SEVERE, null,
                ex);
    }
}
```

In the `GeomController` I am inheriting `Scene` from inherited `Stage` of main class to a `FXMLController` with:

```
public void setMainApp(MoncGUI badGUI) {
    this.myGUI = myGUI;
}

public void setMyStage(Stage stage) {
    this.geoStage = stage;
}
```

I declare another function in this controller as

```
private void fixSetup() {
    geoStage.setTitle("Testing");
    System.out.println("fixSetup :  Height = " + geoStage.getHeight()+"  Width = "+geoStage.getWidth());
    System.out.println("Scene Height " + geoStage.getScene().getHeight()+" Width "+geoStage.getScene().getWidth());
    newScene = geoStage.getScene();

    System.out.println("Scene Height " + geoScene.getHeight()+" Width "+geoScene.getWidth());
    final Scene geoScene = new Scene(camV, drawWidth, drawHeight, true);
    geoScene.setFill(new RadialGradient(225, 0.85, centerX, centerY,
            drawWidth, false,
            CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop[]{new Stop(0f, Color.BLUE),
                new Stop(1f, Color.LIGHTBLUE)}));
    buildCamera(geoScene);
    Context3D context = Context3D.getInstance(camV);
    lightSetting(context);
    axis = buildAxes();
    camV.add(axis);
}
```

The `FXMLController` initiates action as

```
@FXML
void doShapeCyl(ActionEvent event) {
    if (initialized == 0) {
        System.out.println("Processing initialized=0");
        fixSetup();
        initialized = 1;
    }
    drawCylSolid();
}
```

Lastly there is one function as

```
void complete() {
    camV.frameCam(geoStage, geoScene);
    MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler(geoScene, camV);
    KeyHandler keyHandler = new KeyHandler(geoStage, geoScene, camV);
    geoStage.setScene(geoScene);
    geoStage.show();
}
```

There may be many functions like drawCylSolid() like drawSphSolid(), drawDiscSolid(), drawTube() etc. I like to associate groups like

```
CameraViewer camV
```

to the scene and define width and height such that the job is equivalent to

```
final Scene geoScene = new Scene(camV, drawWidth, drawHeight, true);
```

while I wish to avoid "`new Scene`" definition as it would be local to this function only and won't be available to FXML initiated functions or function `complete()` at the end.

Comment: Can you not simply cast the Scene to your specific subclass of scene and then call your methods accordingly? I'm a little unclear as to your requirements here. May be easier to answer, if you can post some more of your code and be a little clearer on what you're hoping to achieve. [This](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1) may help you a little.

Comment: @ManoDestra, I am editing the problem to include more coding.

Comment: Actually, when I am using `final Scene geoScene = new Scene(camV, drawWidth, drawHeight, true);` line inside a function in a controller, it is local to that function only. Therefore, other functions are not getting `geoScene` at all. I want global effect if I use this statement in say `initialise()` or other possible function.

Comment: Then expose your Scene object to other classes from your Stage, or pass it to them via their constructors.

Comment: @ManoDestra, I am not clear about your proposition. Suppose, in the `initialize(...)` function I declare `final Scene geoScene = new Scene(camV, drawWidth, drawHeight, true);`. This means `geoScene` is local to the `initialize(...)` function. Now say in other function `fixSetup()` can I use `geoScene=geoStage.getScene()` to receive that particular `geoScene` declared local to `initialize(..)`? I am confused here. I thought that using of `getScene()` is grabbing scene from its parent and not from locally declared one. By the way, both functions belong to same FXMLController.

Comment: When you create your Scene in your start method, then you can either a) pass the created Scene to other objects in their constructors or via a setScene method that you implement in your classes. OR, you can allow access to the Scene from your Stage object (or Screen Manager) publicly so that other classes can refer to it.

Comment: For the moment, I have made a new Stage inside this Controller in which I am plotting geometries which is working fine. Atleast my code is doing its job of generating instrument geometries. However, the negative is that it is not plotting in its parent stage in single window which I wanted.

Comment: Not sure how you're setting this up, but when you create a JavaFX application, you override the start method, which has the stage available to you. You then create a Scene within that and set it on the Stage. You can allow access to the Stage or Scene from this Application class. You could also pass the Stage (and possibly the Scene) to any components built within the scope of your start method.